# Node classifications made via hiera do not show up in PE Console

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have been experimenting with using hiera for node classification. I followed this example: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/complete_example.html

I was able to assign a node of mine two classes as per this json file:

```
{
   "classes" : [ "ntp",
                 "base" ],
...
```

I can see the effects of these class assignments in the puppet runs for my node, but when I look at the node with the Puppet Enterprise 3 Console I only see that the class `pe_mcollective` has been assigned to the node.  Why isn't the Puppet Enterprise Console not aware that my node has been assigned the classes `ntp` and `base`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Puppet documentation related to data sources: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/puppet_assign_configurations.html. The Puppet Enterprise Console does not ingest site.pp, node.pp or Hiera data and therefore such configuration data is not visible in the PE Console interface.